# Jquery each selector vs class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic question related to Jquery selectors.

In my HTML there is a loop table. In some cases I have to hide the whole first column.

I am just curious if I should use each selector of Jquery

```
$('#tableID').find('tr').each(function(){

//Hide the first column

});
```

Or is it better to use some class name to the first column (for ex. "first_col") which will be used for selector only and not for any CSS styling and use it like

```
$('.first_col').hide();
```

I have never used CSS selector, just for selecting elements and not for CSS styling. Is is a good approach or it has disadvantages as I think it will mix the separation of script and CSS logic.

Please share your views for the same.

Comment: There isn't much of a reason to use `.each` if you are doing the same exact thing to all of them. It's more efficient using the second way, since there is no iteration.

Comment: I think the class selector because it doesn't have to fire up JQuery's sizzle engine.

Answer (score 1):

First, `.each()` is a method -- it does something. `$('.first-col')` is a selector -- it just selects the element(s) on which you will do something (using a method). *Probably you know this and wrote it funny, but just in case it's a helpful reminder*

If you don't need to iterate through a collection one-by-one, don't. So, if you can select all required elements in one single selector, then do it. In this case, you can write one selector string that will grab:

```
- 1st col of every row
- EXCEPT the first one
* and then do something (hide) them all
```

Try this:

```
$('table tr td:first-of-type').hide(); //hides first col of every row
```

```js
$('table tr:not(:first-of-type) td:first-of-type').css('background','yellow');
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:8px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The above code says:

```
- select the table
- select every row: except the first one
- select every td: just the first one
- apply this css
```

---

Notes:

Remember that jQuery uses CSS selectors to select elements. The better you know CSS, the better you know jQuery. The better you know jQuery selectors, the better you know CSS. *It's a great world, idn't it?*

Comment: A tip: **:nth-of-type** selector works on tag name only.

Comment: Are you sure? The (functional) code snippet indicates differently. Did you look at it?

Comment: The code snippet is correct! I just reminded **:nth-of-type** is for element type though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo of 2 ways coding [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vqqgynj2/). Have a look in `console` and see differences. In my opinion, we should use `selector` instead of `find` and `each` because performance of `find` and `each` slower about 3-4 times than `selector`.